# Why is my WebView code in onCreateView unreachable?

Tags: android, kotlin

Unreachable code webview kotlin.

I already looked for several solutions but nothing works, someone could help me.

[image: Unreachable code]

```
class ForumFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forum, container, false)

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webView.clearView();
        webView.measure(100, 100);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your function is returning before executing the lines below.
When the function "returns" it's basically doing an exit to the outer scope.

This should do:

```
class ForumFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        webView.clearView();
        webView.measure(100, 100);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forum, container, false)
    }
}
```